# How do I get ffmpeg to concat 1 second from a list of files?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I have about a thousand video clips and I've got ffmpeg and an ffmpeg file list setup like this:

```
file /path/to/1.mp4
file /path/to/2.mp4
...
file /path/to/1000.mp4
```

I want to concatenate the first second of each clip into an output clip. I've experimented with duration and outpoints specified in the file list, but neither seems to do what I want.

Here's the documentation I've read which I found unclear and lacking an example using the full API:  https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat

Here's the closest I've come (concat the entirety of all files at 100x speed):

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i ~/glass-videos.ffmpeg.txt -filter:v "setpts=PTS/100" -an output.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

Your text file should have outpoints set

```
file /path/to/1.mp4
outpoint 1
file /path/to/2.mp4
outpoint 1
...
file /path/to/1000.mp4
outpoint 1
```

then the command is

```
`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -segment_time_metadata 1 -i ~/glass-videos.ffmpeg.txt -filter:v "select=concatdec_select,setpts=N/FR/TB" -an output.mp4`
```

All inputs are assumed to have the same properties i.e. codec, resolution..etc as the concat demuxer requires.

Comment: This is definitely getting closer. I tweaked the command you supplied to this:
`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -segment_time_metadata 1 -i  ~/glass-videos.ffmpeg.txt -filter:v "select=concatdec_select,setpts=PTS/4" -an output.mp4`. This has outpoints at 4 (seconds). When I usd your command and 1 second outpoint, I get a single frame held for the full second. As you can see, even with 4 from each source, it's stuttering/stopping between each clip. What's causing the stuttering?
Here's the 4s output: https://filebin.net/pis3czf1wckt0ea0/seconds-2.mp4?t=bhtsc7rv

Comment: Share the readout of `ffprobe file` for the first 3-4 files in your list.

Comment: Share these files, if you can.